# How to get dom element using name attribute in angular 2 or 4 or 5

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, angular2-template

I have template which has multiple image(img) tags inside it, all these are iterated in foreach loop and modifiing this img src attribute/properties in typescript file.

HTML code:

```
<div *ngFor="let lt of list">
<div>
    <a href="{{lt.url}}" target="_self">
      <img mat-card-image name="{{lt.name}}" class="image" src="" placement="top" container="body">
    </a>
</div>
<div>
    <a href="{{lt.url}}" target="_self">
      <img mat-card-image name="{{lt.name}}" class="image" src="" placement="top" container="body">
    </a>
</div>
<div>
    <a href="{{lt.url}}" target="_self">
      <img mat-card-image name="{{lt.name}}" class="image" src="" placement="top" container="body">
    </a>
</div>
</div>
```

code in typescript file,

```
ngOnInit() {
    for (const lt of list) {
        if (lt.title === 'xyz') {
          lt.title = 'XYZ';
        }
        if (lt.appFlag) {
          this.getIcon(lt.name);
        }
    }
}


  private getIcon(name: string): void {
  const imageUrl = this.service.createURL('abc');

  // how to get img tag using property/attribute name(name here is unique item name) from HTML without using document.querySelector etc.
  ....
  ....
  //const img = this.name.nativeElement.name;

  //console.log('inside getIcon:img', img);


  if (img) {
    img['src'] = imageUrl;
  }
});
}
```

Comment: Without using document.querySelector or document.getElementByName etc, is it possible with any Angular feature like an ElementREf etc

Comment: is that worked for you ???

Answer (score 1):

you can get access by creating `directive` and attaching with your element , below is code for that , Directive below make use of `ElementRef` which inturn allows you to interact with `nativeHtml` element.

---

ImageElementDirective

```
import { ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Directive } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector:"[imageElement]"
})
class ImageElement {
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
  }

  getImage() : any {
    return el.nativeElement;
  }
}
```

Component.ts

```
//this will give you all image element , 
//you should use for loop or foreach to perform operation 
//you want
@ViewChildren(ImageElement) allImageElement;
```

Component.html

```
<img imageElement ..rest>
<img imageElement ..rest>
```